# Append checkbox and label to div

Tags: jquery, html

My html structure is like this

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type"checkbox">First</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type"checkbox">Second</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type"checkbox">Third</label>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make it like this

```
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type"checkbox">
  <label>First</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type"checkbox">
  <label>Second</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type"checkbox">
  <label>Third</label>
</div>
```

I tried this

```
$(":checkbox")
.prependTo(".checkbox");
```

But it appends all checkbox to all div

Update:
 I want to update using JavaScript I don't have control over HTML

Comment: on which event do  you need it??

Comment: @RohitKumar I think it's page load

Comment: on `jQuery(document).ready`

Comment: @ronroo I guess, you want to change this using Javascript on page load and you don't have control on HMTL markup, if that is the case update the question properly

Comment: Do you want it in pure Javascript or in Jquery.

Comment: @Rakshit Anything with simple method is fine

Comment: Use `each` to loop through the divs, and then `find` the checkbox element within each one individually, and append it to the same current element (which you get using `$(this)`.)

Comment: @CBroe I tried this   `$('.checkbox').children(':checkbox').each(function(){
  $(this).find(':checkbox').appendTo('.checkbox'); 
});` but not working. Am I doing any it in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox")[0].innerHTML="<input type='checkbox'><label>First</label>";
document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox")[1].innerHTML="<input type='checkbox'><label>Second</label>";
document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox")[2].innerHTML="<input type='checkbox'><label>Third</label>";
```